# PHP issue with email links in outlook

Tags: php, email, outlook

I am trying to make a php script that sends the user a confirmation email including a link that has to be clicked for the user account to be activated.

That has been tested to work fine with for example gmail email account.

```
$message = "Confirm your email.
            Click the link below to confirm your account.
            https://testonly.000webhostapp.com/web_emailconfirm.php?user_name=$user_name&confirm_code=$confirmCode";

mail($email,"Confirmation email",$message,"From: doNotRepply@mytestcode.com");
```

Once the link in the email is clicked, it opens a website that internally runs another PHP script for the verification, and the users database is updated with some new values.

**The problem is: it seems like, in Outlook**, just opening the email seems to be triggering the link, because the php code is running and the users database is being updated, **before actually clicking the link.**

What is going on here?

Comment: Is link not in anchor tag intentionally?

Comment: sorry for my "newbie" ignorance...what do you mean with `in anchor tag`? i took the code for sending the email from another place and it works so....

Comment: <a href="link-url">Click Here to verify</a>

Comment: ok in that case, yes it is not in anchor tag intentionally, at least it works like that, however i dont know if it is the correct way to do that

Comment: why not give it a try

Comment: sure why not, I will, thanks.

Comment: @reenleedr, I am not sure how to mix the tag with the string in `$message =` so that the link shows the text and it is also clickable...

Comment: I have posted it in answer

Answer (score 0):

Try Changing

```
$message = "Confirm your email.
        Click the link below to confirm your account.
        https://testonly.000webhostapp.com/web_emailconfirm.php?user_name=$user_name&confirm_code=$confirmCode";
```

to

```
$message = "Confirm your email.
        Click the link below to confirm your account.
        <a href='https://testonly.000webhostapp.com/web_emailconfirm.php?user_name=$user_name&confirm_code=$confirmCode'>https://testonly.000webhostapp.com/web_emailconfirm.php?user_name=$user_name&confirm_code=$confirmCode</a>";
```

**UPDATE**

you should also pass along HTML mail headers

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
```

you can learn more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/Php/func_mail_mail.asp)

Comment: check example 3 on the link i provided